# R corrplot - colorir baseado nos valores de correlação

Tags: r

Tenho um dataframe binário (53115 rows; 520 colunas) e quero fazer um gráfico de correlação. Quero colorir os valores de correlação a vermelho se forem maiores ou iguais a 0.95, caso contrátio, a azul.

```
correl = abs(round(cor(bin_mat),2))

pdf("corrplot.pdf", width = 200, height = 200)  

a = corrplot(correl, order = "hclust", addCoef.col = "black", number.cex=0.8, cl.lim = c(0,1), col=c(rep("deepskyblue",19) ,"red"))  

dev.off()
```

Consegui obter o gráfico mas em muitos casos obtenho uma coloração errada ( ver gráfico abaixo no valor 0.91).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

data file:[file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/1kfnl5t0a5fodko/dataset.csv/file)

Como posso corrigir este problema para ter uma correta coloração?

Comment: A função `corrplot` pertence a qual pacote? Auxilie as pessoas que irão te ajudar informando o nome dos pacotes que estão sendo carregados para realizar a análise.

Comment: @isabelinho É sempre bom incluir a informação de todos os pacotes adicionais que está utilizando. E como seus dados são muito grandes, é melhor incluir uma amostra pequena deles. Ou, se os dados em si não forem relevantes (como é o seu caso), você pode usar uma das bases de dados inclusas na base do R.

Answer (score 6):

O problema está em como a opção `col`, quando paletas personalizadas são utilizadas, funciona junto com `cl.lim`. A documentação do pacote fala sobre isso. Veja o que acontece com e sem `cl.lim`. Estou usando a base mtcars, inclusa no R, de exemplo, e usando corte em 0.8 para facilitar a visualização:

```
correl <- cor(mtcars)

library(corrplot)

par(mfrow = c(1,2))

  corrplot(abs(correl),
    addCoef.col = "black",
    cl.lim = c(0, 1),
    col = c(rep("deepskyblue", 9) ,"red") 
  )  

  corrplot(abs(correl),
    addCoef.col = "black",
    col = c(rep("deepskyblue", 9) ,"red") 
  )
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Correlações ocorrem em um contínuo entre -1 e 1; `corrplot` mapeia as cores para essa faixa (remover o sinal das correlações é simplesmente uma péssima ideia) e não consegue ajustar a legenda quando a paleta é personalizada.

Além disso, ao contrário do valor de p, onde o que interessa é se está acima ou abaixo de um limite, a intensidade do valor do índice de correlação é importante. Por isso `corrplot` não foi feito pensando em escalas qualitativas.

Uma maneira de resolver seu caso, mantendo os sinais, é simplesmente gerar as cores para funcionarem no intervalo -1:1, com as divisões que quer. A legenda ficará inútil, então corte-a:

```
corrplot(correl,
  addCoef.col = "black",
  col = c("red", rep("deepskyblue", 8) ,"red"),
  cl.pos = 'n'
)
```

Apenas modifique o valor em `rep` para o seu caso (38). Mas fica o conselho de usar uma paleta contínua.